# Microsoft Edge Extension with native messaging and non-persistent connection does not work

Tags: c++, c, native, messaging, microsoft-edge-extension

I have created a Microsoft Edge Extension with native messaging but I cannot make it work with non-persistent connections.

The example given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging) is not useful in my particular case:

The example (Random Number Generator) shows how two UWP applications can communicate where the client communicates with the server when the server is already running. In Edge Extensions with Native Messaging (and mine is based on the Digital Signing and Secure Input examples), I have a W32 applications where the server is NOT running when the message arrives from the page via the extension.

I have checked out all the samples I could find [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos) and none are using "non-persistent" connections which I need:

I have also tried using `runtime.sendNativeMessage` in my Edge extension but this only works for the first message.

I do not have an interactive html page whereby the user can start a connection with the `runtime.connectNative`. That's why it has to be a "non-persistent" connection using `runtime.sendNativeMessage` to `start/query/get-response` from the native application in a similar way to the one used by Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Please post the non working code in your question. All those links don't help much to solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
 and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks [Shim-Sao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8319683/shim-sao). But I have already reworded my original question because it was put on-hold. The amount of code associated with this is far too big to include in the question. The crunch point is that the use of runtime.sendNativeMessage API in an Edge extension is insufficient to make it into a non-persistent connection, i.e. one that starts/exchanges messages and then closes the native app. So, the question is what else to do besides using runtime.sendNativeMessage() to make an Edge extension work with non-persistent connections?

Comment: From the doc, it says *Microsoft Edge will terminate the connection after every messages' response has been received.* You could follow [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging#non-persistent) which shows the non-persistent connection. Besides, for callbacks, *Edge uses the AppServiceRequest object's SendResponseAsync method to let the app send a ValueSet object back to the extension* instead of runtime.sendNativeMessage.

Comment: Thank you [Yu Zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11490347/yu-zhou). But you will notice that the example you recommend is the same as I refer to in my question and it is not very useful to me. It refers to the Random Number Generator sample which I have checked out. It is not the same thing as an Edge extension although they both use comms between two UWP apps.  Finally, in Edge extensions, SendResponseAsync method is used regardless of whether you use runtime.sendNativeMessage API (i.e. non-persistent connection) or runtime.connectNative API (i.e. persistent connection).

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate API's in Edge for persistence and Non-persistence connection. The only difference is: for persistence connection we will keep the connection open after it is successfully established. We can close it till the task is done. Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/AppServices/cs/AppServicesClient/KeepConnectionOpenScenario.xaml.cs#L41).

However, for non-persistence connections, we would release the connect as soon as the response is received and stored as an AppServiceResponse. [This sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging#non-persistent) is very clear where we can see the AppServiceConnection object lasts only for one connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you [Fangfang Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5271974/fangfang-wu-msft).But I am afraid I disagree.The sample you refer to is anything but clear. I have checked it out. It refers to two UWP applications where one is the AppServicesProvider and the other is a client. This is not the case in Edge exten. with nativeMessaging.wrt not having separate APIs, again I think you are mistaken.Persistent connections are started from background.js by a call that uses a port,i.e. port = browser.runtime.connectNative.Only after this can you send messages to the native app.e.g. DigitalSigning sample

Comment: I continue... [Fangfang Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5271974/fangfang-wu-msft) :-). In fact I have used the runtime.sendNativeMessage API (for non-persistent connections) in my Edge extension. And it works but only for the first message. So there are definitely two different APIs possible in Edge just as is the case for Chrome and FF extensions. You can see this in Mozilla's Documentation that is also referred to from Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this issue and converted my Edge extension from a persistent to a non-persistent connection extension.

 Assuming you start with an extension similar to the one [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos), the central ideas in converting the extension to a non-persistent one are as follows:

1. Remove all JavaScript code associated with connect/disconnect from the content.js and background.js
2. Move the call that launches the win32 application from OnBackgroundActivated() into OnAppServiceRequestReceived()
3. The last step ensures that we only call

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync()
```

, when we actually receive a message from Edge.

4. The win32 application is then called with the payload of the message from Edge. The win32 application communicates the result back to Edge via the AppServiceConnection in the following calls:

```
        // Send message to the win32 application component and wait for response
        AppServiceResponse centennialResponse = await this.centennialConnection.SendMessageAsync(args.Request.Message);
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(centennialResponse.Message);
```

5. The above steps result in a call that starts with browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage() in background.js which is picked up by OnAppServiceRequestReceived(). The latter launches the win32 application and passes the message to it via the AppServiceConnection made in centennialConnection. It awaits the result and sends the response back to background.js.
6. The calls in the last step all happen without a session or a persistent connection ever being established between the background script and the background task.

The reliability of our extension has improved a great deal as a result of the above changes.